# Storing Google Refresh Token in Database?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am building a web application which provide sign in with google option. Initially we ask `profile` and `email` scopes from user(offline access). In return we get a `code`.

Using this code, I request a `refresh_token` and then an `access_token`. Both these tokens are stored on client side in cookies(you might say storing `refresh_token` on client side is a bad idea).

In my app, I have provided user to be able to access his drive files. For this I use incremental scopes. So I ask drive permission from user. In return I get a `code` -> new `refresh_token` -> new `access_token`.

**But the problem is :**

When user clears cookies or log out. Then when he logs in, new `refresh_token` and `access_token` are generated which only includes scopes for `profile` and `email`. So I have to ask user again for his drive permissions. I don't want to ask user every time for his drive permission after he already gave them.

**Possible Solution :**

Storing the `refresh_token` on server side?? Is this the right way??

Comment: What i did for a project I'm working in is to encrypt them send the to dynamo db where the the refresh token can the be accessed so you can generate a new access token and then just decrypt it when you retreive  it.

Comment: @JosephMckenzie So after logging the user(you get an access token) you fetch the refresh token from db and generate a new access token and overwrite the old access token??

Comment: yep i can share the basic code with you if you would like

Comment: Sure man that will be helpful

Comment: I too have the same question, but to me it seems like a security vulnerability to store the refresh token as if your DB is ever compromised the attacker will suddenly have google drive access to all your users, unless I have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach recommended by Google:

> The application should store the refresh token for future use and use the access token to access a Google API. Once the access token expires, the application uses the refresh token to obtain a new one.

From here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2